# Foreign Key for either-or column?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have a foreign key that requires either column A or column B to have a value, but not both.  And the foreign key for column A matches Table 1 and the foreign key for column B matches Table 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A check constraint can handle this. If this is SQL Server, something like this will work:

```
create table A (Id int not null primary key)
go
create table B (Id int not null primary key)
go
create table C (Id int not null primary key, A_Id int null, B_Id int null)
go
alter table C add constraint FK_C_A
foreign key (A_Id) references A (Id)
go
alter table C add constraint FK_C_B
foreign key (B_Id) references B (Id)
go
alter table C add constraint CK_C_OneIsNotNull
check (A_Id is not null or B_Id is not null)
go
alter table C add constraint CK_C_OneIsNull
check (A_Id is null or B_Id is null)
go
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which database you're working with.  If you want a table `Foo` that has FK relationships to `Table1` and to `Table2` but only one at a time, then you'll need to set up either some sort of [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) (my links assume SQL Server, but the ideas's the same) or [Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to enforce your rule that only one column have a value.

Answer (score 1):

it is not necessary that a column have values in it at that time of applying foreign key,but the column name would be same and the data types as well.