# Foreign Key Relationship with one of Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a language map table that each entry has the possibility of a foreign key relationship with a few different tables. **What is the best schema to deal with this configuration?**

**Tables:** LanguageMap, TableA, TableB

These are the two possibility:

**1. Lookup Column Method - No Foreign Key Constraints:**

```
Create Table LanguageMap (
   Id int not null primary key,
   Language nvarchar not null,
   Value nvarchar not null,
   Type nvarchar not null, -- 'TableA', 'TableB', etc.
   ForeignTableId int not null -- Is Foreign key to another table dependent on the type of the row.
)
```

**2. Multiple Foreign Key Columns**

```
create Table LanguageMap(
   Id int not null primary key,
   Language nvarchar not null,
   Value nvarchar not null,
   Type nvarchar not null, -- 'Activity', 'Verb', etc.
   TableAId int null,
   TableBId int null
)
alter table LanguageMap add constraint FK_LanguageMap_TableA
foreign key (TableAId) references TableA (Id)

alter table LanguageMap add constraint FK_LanguageMap_TableA
foreign key (TableBId) references TableB (Id)

alter table LanguageMap add constraint CK_LanguageMap_OneIsNotNull
check (TableAId is not null or TableBId is not null)
go
alter table LanguageMap add constraint CK_LanguageMap_OneIsNull
check (TableAId is null or TableBId is null)
go
```

The foreign key constraints are based on [Foreign Key for either-or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300357/foreign-key-for-either-or-column)

Comment: Can you show a bit of sample data to clarify what is stored in TableA and TableB? Do they have the same schema as each other. Also are there only 2 different tables you are linking to or is it just limited to 2 for the purpose of this question?

Comment: I'm still writing the schema so I'm not sure how many tables there will be. But assume that there schemas will be radically different and there will be a least four of them: ie TableA, TableB, TableC, TableD. Maybe more. Why is the sample data relevant?

Comment: I was trying to work out if the schema/data would be similar in the tables.

Answer (score 2):

There is another alternative, called "Shared Primary Key".  You can look this up.  If TableA, TableB, TableC, etc.  all "inherit" their PK as a copy of the PK from some Master table,  called "TableMaster" for example,  then you can just use that as an FK in LanguageMap.

The correct joins will select the correct instances.

The shared primary key is often used in conjunction with a design pattern called "Class Table Inheritance".  Without knowing what TableA, TableB, TableC, etc. are about,  I can't say whether Class Table Inheritance is relevant to your case.

In any event, look up both "Shared Primary Key" and "Class Table Inheritance" for further reading.
There are tags with those names in this area.

Comment: A great post that discusses Share Primary key: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server