# Enforce 1:0..1 relationship with EF6 Database First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my model, I have three tables, `Storage`, `Haul` and `StoragePlace`. One storage can *either* be a place or haul. For the `StoragePlace`, I already achieved a 1:0..1 relationship. The problem is the `Haul` entity.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Haul
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    ID_Storage INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Arrival DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(), 
    Depature DATETIME NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Haul_to_Storage FOREIGN KEY (ID_Storage) REFERENCES Storage(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO

/** --- See edit below --
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQX_Storage
    ON Haul(ID_Storage)
    WHERE ID_Storage IS NOT NULL;
GO
**/

--------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE dbo.Storage
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Description1 NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Description2 NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    AddedBy NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

--------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE dbo.StoragePlace
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_PlantArea INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_StoragePlace_to_Storage FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Storage(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_StoragePlace_to_PlantArea FOREIGN KEY (ID_PlantArea) REFERENCES PlantArea(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

My thought was, that `UQX_Storage` would trigger EF6 to accept a 1:0..1 relationship between `Haul` and `Storage`. Certainly, this doesn't work; it still insists on a 1:* relationship, which, from my understanding, shall not be possible with this model above.

How can I enforce the intended 1:0..1 relationship between `Haul` and `Storage`?

**EDIT:**

I just realized, that the `ID_Storage` field can never be `NULL`, so I replaced the `UQX_Storage` "constraint" with a simple `ID_Storage INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,`. However, that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300357/foreign-key-for-either-or-column

Comment: @SteveGreene I already found that post. This does help with database, but not with EF6, though.