# Ecto - Foreign key constraint on table A for table B or C, but not both B & C

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, ecto

Let's say that `table A` can belong to either `table B` or `table C`, but not both.

It seems that it is possible to use foreign key constraints for this scenario [in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17300357/1911755).

How could this relationship be represented in Elixir's Ecto library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can structure this as using a separate column for each foreign key constraint and then guaranteeing that only one is populated:

```
create table A (
    . . . 
    b_id int,
    c_id int,
    foreign key (b_id) references b(b_id),
    foreign key (c_id) references c(c_id),
    check (b_id is null or c_id is null)
)
```